# Add square bracket in first and last word of a sentence (multiple sentence) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I will input few sentences and the output will be wrap up every sentence with square bracket.I have tried so far:

```
  $('.addCharacter').click(function(event) {
    var textareaInput=$('.textareaInput').val();
    var myString = '[' + textareaInput + ']';
    console.log(myString);
  });
```

**Input:**

```
demo text one  
demo text two  
demo text three
```

**Output:**

```
[demo text one
demo text two
demo text three]
```

But I want output should be:

```
[demo text one]
[demo text two]
[demo text three]
```

I think it can be done with **regex**.I am not so good in **regex**.Could anyone one tell me the way?

Comment: **[this](https://regex101.com/r/bA6oR5/1)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this line

```
 var myString = '[' + textareaInput + ']';
```

with

```
 var myString = '[' + textareaInput.split("\n").join("]\n[") + ']';
```

If you are getting an extra space then use this regex (`/\s*\n\s*/`) for splitting

```
 var myString = '[' + textareaInput.split(/\s*\n\s*/).join("]\n[") + ']';
```

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud: This solution keeps the spaces at the beginning/end of line, and you [said it is not what you need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410521/add-square-bracket-in-first-and-last-word-of-a-sentence-multiple-sentence-in-j/37410587?noredirect=1#comment62327977_37410587). That is somewhat inconsistent.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew handled the same as well. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I still think I have a better one. Yours will remove empty/whitespace only lines.

Answer (score 5):

Use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with regex having [`m(multiline)` modifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters)

> multiline; treat beginning and end characters (^ and $) as working over multiple lines (i.e., match the beginning or end of each line (delimited by \n or \r), not only the very beginning or end of the whole input string) (Taken from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) )

```js
var textareaInput = `demo text one  
demo text two 
demo text three`;

var myString = textareaInput.replace(/^[^\S\r\n]*(.*?)[^\S\r\n]*$/gm, '[$1]');

console.log(myString);
```

---

**UPDATE :** Updated the regex to match white spaces(which is not newline) in at the beginning and ending. ( as in **@WiktorStribiżew** answer )

---

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/vW0lE6/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

Or use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with callback and apply **[`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)**

```js
var textareaInput = `demo text one  
demo text two 
demo text three`;

var myString = textareaInput.replace(/^.*$/gm, function(m) {
  return '[' + m.trim() + ']'
});

console.log(myString);
```

---

Using **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** and **[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** can be do the job that approach is also added here, instead of **[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** using **[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** you can do something like this for fun :)

```js
var textareaInput = `demo text one  
demo text two 
demo text three`;

var myString = textareaInput.split(/\n/).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return (a.length ? a + '\n' : '') + '[' + b.trim() + ']'
}, '')

console.log(myString);
```

Comment: Every last word of a sentence there is a space in your way.But it should not have.By the help me a lot.

Comment: And it is a bit different from mine as `.+?` requires at least 1 character. So, if a string is all whitespace, your output line will be `[ ]`, not `[]`. Also, since `\s` matches a newline, empty or whitespace only lines will get shrunk/merged.

Comment: Yes, just `[ ]` does not match a non-breaking space and some other Unicode spaces.

Answer (score 3):

A non-regex way:

```js
var textareaInput = `demo text one  
    demo text two  


    demo text three   `;
var res = '[' + textareaInput.split("\n").map(x => x.trim()).join("]\n[") + ']';
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + res + "</pre>";
```

You can use a regex approach, too:

```
var myString = textareaInput.replace(/^[^\S\r\n]*(.*?)[^\S\r\n]*$/gm, "[$1]");
```

The `^[^\S\r\n]*(.*?)[^\S\r\n]*$` pattern will match any line (due to the `/m` modifier that makes `^` match  the line start and `$` match the line end), even an empty one (due to the `*` quantifier that matches *zero or more occurrences*), and replace with a `[`, the line **up to the last whitespace(s)**, and a `]` (`$1` is a backreference to the Group 1 value).

Details:

- `^` - line start
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - zero or more **horizontal** whitespaces (not removing empty lines)
- `(.*?)` - any characters but a newline, as few as possible, up to the first
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `$` - end of line

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI1hW4/3)

```js
var re = /^[^\S\r\n]*(.*?)[^\S\r\n]*$/gm; 
var str = `demo text one  
demo text two  
demo text three`;
var result = str.replace(re, '[$1]');
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + result + "</pre>";
```

Comment: Every last word of a sentence there is a space in your way.But it should not have.By the help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method instead of RegEx:

```
$('.addCharacter').click(function(event) {
    var textareaInput=$('.textareaInput').val().split('\n');
    var output = '';
    $(textareaInput).each( function() {
      output += '[' + this + ']\n';
    });
    console.log(output);
});
```

In this case it will create an Array of all newlines and you will be able to concat each new line your way.